# Android Studio - List View Image Button returning wrong positions

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, simplecursoradapter, cursor-position

- In my Android Studio app I have a list of songs  from the SD card which I adapt into a list using a custom adapter and a cursor
- in the list view, each list item has a "play" button next to it
- when the button is clicked, it will start an intent containing the correspondings song ID
- unfortunately it keeps passing an incorrect ID and when I check the position, it is nearly always "6" even though I click on different list items that are not in position 6

here is the code for iamge button being clicked

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public Context context;
public Cursor cursor;
public int layout;
public String[] selection;
public int[] resources;

public View convertView;

ImageButton playButton;
TextView songName;
TextView artist;
ImageView albumArt;



public Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] selection, int[] resources, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, cursor, selection, resources, flags);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.resources = resources;
    this.selection = selection;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //inflates list
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);

        songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(resources[0]);
        artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(resources[1]);
        albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(resources[2]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        final Cursor thisCursor = cursor;
        final Context thisContext = context;

        playButton = (ImageButton)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.listPlay);

        //set artist and text
        songName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[0])));
        artist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[1])));


        //artwork
        final Uri ART_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

        try {
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ART_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[2])));
            Bitmap songCoverArt = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
            albumArt.setImageBitmap(songCoverArt);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        //if play button is selected
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = thisCursor.getPosition();
                //returns wrong position and id's?


                //get id of song based on that position
                String stringID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[3]));
                //create bundle to send
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //add position to bundle
                bundle.putString("ID", stringID);
                Intent intent = new Intent(thisContext, Home.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                //flag to allow this out of activty context
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                thisContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
```

}

- please note that cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[3]))) == MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
- if anyone could help me I would be so greatful!

Comment: Can you please show your complete CursorAdapter...! Because its important to debug the problem

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing the whole code, but most probably you're getting the index of the current view, not the position of the item in the list.

Comment: I've got all the code here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should use the button's tag instead of a `final` variable(This will cause a Memory leak). I already ran into the same issue in the past, you should use the below adapter to resolve the issue,

```
 public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public Context context;
public Cursor cursor;
public int layout;
public String[] selection;
public int[] resources;

public View convertView;

ImageButton playButton;
TextView songName;
TextView artist;
ImageView albumArt;



public Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] selection, int[] resources, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, cursor, selection, resources, flags);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.resources = resources;
    this.selection = selection;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        //inflates list
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);

        songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(resources[0]);
        artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(resources[1]);
        albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(resources[2]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        //final Cursor thisCursor = cursor;
        final Context thisContext = context;

        playButton = (ImageButton)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.listPlay);

        //set artist and text
        songName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[0])));
        artist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[1])));


        //artwork
        final Uri ART_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

        try {
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ART_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[2])));
            Bitmap songCoverArt = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
            albumArt.setImageBitmap(songCoverArt);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        playButton.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[3])));
        //if play button is selected
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //int position = thisCursor.getPosition();
                //returns wrong position and id's?


                //get id of song based on that position
                String stringID = (String) v.getTag();
                //create bundle to send
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //add position to bundle
                bundle.putString("ID", stringID);
                Intent intent = new Intent(thisContext, Home.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                //flag to allow this out of activty context
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                thisContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: both of these methods worked! for some reason the last couple items in the list view still mess up either way but the rest is fine. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

**first** avoid always doing data manipulation based on `position` (yes sometimes works, take a look at this video : The world of ListView https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).

try this:

```
            final String stringID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(selection[3])); //make it final before setting the click listener

            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {

            //create bundle to send
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //add position to bundle
            bundle.putString("ID", stringID);
            Intent intent = new Intent(thisContext, Home.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            //flag to allow this out of activty context
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            thisContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

i think you gonna need also to make Context final.

Comment: both of these methods worked! for some reason the last couple items in the list view still mess up either way but the rest is fine. Thank you for helping :)